# Minimum and Maximum values of variance

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ be an arbitrary random variable  takes values in $\{0,1,2,...,10\}$. What are the minimum and  maximum values of variance of random variable $X$?

Comment: Variance is nonnegative, right? Can it take value $0$ here?

Answer (score 2):

Just some hints.

The problem is the same as if $X$ took values in $\{-5,-4,\dots,5\}$.

The variance is $E(X^2) - E(X)^2$. For the maximum value, it is possible, simultaneously, for $E(X^2)$ to be maximal while $E(X)^2$ is minimal.

For the minimum, what do you think it is?